# Calculate field with value based on select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have a select statement which returns Customer Numbers that are primary.

What I would like to do for those returned, I would like to have another column that is for customerRole. For customerRole the value should be either primary or secondary.

My current select statement is bringing those that are primary and based on that select statement. I would like to have a customerRole column that shows these as primary. Then I would like to use this same column with my other select statement to show those that are secondary. When they are ran together I would like to see something like:

accountNumber: 1234455  CustomerRole: Primary
AccountNumber: 3245454 CustomerRole: Secondary

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this? Here is my select to get primary numbers:

```
   SELECT 
     F.CustomerNumber
      FROM ods.CustomerFact F
      JOIN ods.holderDim AD
       ON  F.HolderRowNumber = AD.HolderRowNumber
      JOIN ods.holderOwesDim B  
       ON F.PrimaryHolderNumber = B.SecondaryHolderNumber
```

Comment: "other select statement"...can you show it? "ran together"...how exactly? You mean a UNION statement perhaps? Please be clear. We don't know your application, your data structure etc.

Comment: Anyway, it _sounds_ like you just want to do something like `SELECT 
     F.CustomerNumber, [CustomerRole] = 'Primary'` to output the same fixed value for all rows returned from that SELECT statement, but it's not entirely clear. Sample data and expected results might help.

Comment: P.S. it's not clear what "primary" and "secondary" actually mean in terms of your data structure, and it's unclear why you can't output both types of number in a single select - if they're both roles which a user can hold, are they not stored in the same table? I smell a rat in terms of table structure, but don't know enough to be certain.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT c.CustomerNumber,
       (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                          FROM ods.holderDim hd
                          WHERE c.PrimaryHolderNumber = hd.SecondaryHolderNumber
                         ) AND
                  EXISTS (SELECT 1
                          FROM ods.holderOwesDim hod
                          WHERE c.PrimaryHolderNumber = hod.SecondaryHolderNumber
             THEN 'Primary' ELSE 'Secondary'
                         )
        END) as role
FROM ods.CustomerFact c;
```

Comment: I believe you are correct however there is an error being thrown starting at the THEN clause do you know why?